# How to remove a header element from a SOAP request before posting the message to server

Tags: java

I have a SOAP request like below. Before sending the request to server, I want to remove "SessionType" and "SessionToken" from the SOAP Header.

Please guide.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Stateless</SessionType>
      <SessionToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">xkhdj</SessionToken>
      <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">xyz</UsernameToken>
      <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">**********</PasswordText>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <GetCustomerPreference_Input xmlns="http://siebel.com/CustomUI">
         <CustNumber>FR7810</CustNumber>
         <Country>France</Country>
         <LOB/>
      </GetCustomerPreference_Input>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Regards,
Milan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could use the below to clear the header and then set the required elements.

```
soapHeaders.removeContents();
```

Comment: Where to exactly use this logic ?

Comment: Which logic are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
    SOAPEnvelope env = msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
    SOAPHeader header = env.getHeader();
    header.detachNode();
```

But it will remove the complete header from the request if you want to do so. For removing specific header you need to write custom code like mentioned here

https://technology.amis.nl/2011/05/16/how-to-remove-unwanted-soap-header-elements-in-jax-ws/
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_remove.asp